# How to generate custom auto number in ms access database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Public Sub CustomID()
    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT Max(Right(Delievery Number,4)) As Delievery Number From tbl_monitoring " '[Delievery Number] From tbl_monitoring
    command = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    reader = command.ExecuteReader
    reader.Read()

    If Not reader.HasRows Or IsDBNull(reader.Item("Delievery Number")) Then
        txtDel.Text = "Del" & "0001"
    Else
        Dim Idnew As Integer = CInt(reader.Item("Delievery Number"))
        Idnew += 1
        txtDel.Text = "Del" & Idnew.ToString("0000")
    End If

    reader.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar in the right queries in database please help me.. it says that there's something wrong in the syntax. and the reader is unhandled.

Comment: The purpose of an autoincrement ID is to provide a unique identifier for each row.  An id with information encoded into it `Del###` is a bad idea for a PK.  Second, allowing the user to edit it in a textbox is a very bad idea if it is a PK.  Third, `SELECT Max(` may fail eventually when rows get deleted

Comment: Now i understand thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first point out that it's not an auto-number if you're generating it manually.

As for the issue, this is a symptom of having spaces in column names.  If possible, change the name of that column from 'Delievery Number' to 'DelieveryNumber' or, if it's English, use the correct spelling and name it 'DeliveryNumber'.

If you can't change the column name then you must escape it in your SQL, i.e. use '[Delievery Number]'.